# get current time in specific timezone using c++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, time

My code should work on linux & windlows as well.
I want to get current time in YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS. Default timezone is UTC+08, where as my system can be located in any timezone.

It would be great help if you can help me with c++ code (I do not have c++11 , 14 compiler)

I saw one solution - use time to get the current time in UTC and then manipulate the TZ environment variable to your destination timezone. Then use localtime_r to convert to that timezone's local time.

But not sure how to achieve this with c++ that will work for Windows and linux.

Comment: I have used the newer [CCTZ](https://github.com/google/cctz) library for this.  Can you use that?

Comment: Both [CCTZ](https://github.com/google/cctz) and [Howard Hinnant's timezone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) require `<chrono>` which was introduced in C++11.  But yes, either of these could easily do the job (in C++11/14/17).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the boost library `boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp`.

From there you can then simply get the current local time like so:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime curr_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
```

And it has methods to turn it into a string as required:

```
std::string curr_time_str = to_simple_string(curr_time);
```

And back to the ptime object:

```
curr_time = boost::posix_time::time_from_string(curr_time_str);
```

etc.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html

Comment: I can not use boost library..:( any other solution will help

Answer (score 0):

Should work on most platforms:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{  
         time_t ts = 0;
              struct tm t;
              char buf[16];
              ::localtime_r(&ts, &t);
              ::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%z", &t);
              std::cout << "Current timezone: " << buf << std::endl;
              ::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Z", &t);
              std::cout << "Current timezone: " << buf << std::end;
        ...
```

}